# To get the six digit value after the decimal point without round-off

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

I have a small question on getting the 6 digit value after the decimal point without truncate.

Example:

**Input:**

```
id  amt
2   256.25356890
```

**Output:**

```
id  amt
2   256.253568
```

i.e. The `amt` column should not be round off:

```
id amt
2  256.253569 (this round-off should not happen)
```

Comment: In SQL Server or Oracle? They're two distinct, different DBMSes.

Answer (score 0):

use `ROUND(256.25356890, 6, 1)` in sql server
and `TRUNC(256.25356890,6)` in oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @X float = 2256.25356890;

SELECT ROUND(@X * 1000000.0, 0) / 1000000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a solution of your problem

**Just run this function**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create  FUNCTION DecimalWithOutRoundingOff
(
    @DecimalInput varchar(50)
)
RETURNS varchar(100) -- or whatever length you need
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @start INT, @end INT,@num1 varchar(100),@num2 varchar(100)
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX('.', @DecimalInput) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@DecimalInput) + 1 BEGIN 
    IF @end = 0  
        SET @end = LEN(@DecimalInput) + 1
    set @num2 =  Substring(SUBSTRING(@DecimalInput, @start, @end - @start),1,6)
    set @num1 = substring(@DecimalInput,1,CHARINDEX('.',@DecimalInput)-1)
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @end = CHARINDEX('.', @DecimalInput, @start)

END 

return @num1 +'.'+ @num2

END
GO
```

**To use:**

`select dbo.DecimalWithOutRoundingOff(256.25356890)`

**Result:**

`256.253568`